# libcurl_a_debug.lib, libcurl_a.lib are generated instead of libcurld.lib, libcurl.lib

Tags: windows, curl, openssl, windows-10, libcurl

When building the latest *Curl* release (**7.61.0**) on *Windows*, using the scripts provided in *winbuild* folder, the files which are generated are *libcurl_a_debug.lib* (debug) and *libcurl_a.lib* (release), instead of *libcurld.lib* and *libcurl.lib*, as they're usually named.
Am I doing something wrong?

Here's the executed cmd:

```
d:\code\curl-7.61.0\winbuild> nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static WITH_SSL=static MACHINE=x86 DEBUG=yes SSL_PATH=<path>
```

The *openssl* path contains *lib* and *header* folders, with static library and headers - the output of built-from-source *openssl 1.1.1-pre8*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nmake [`Makefile.vc`](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/curl-7_61_0/winbuild/Makefile.vc) which on its turn nmakes [`MakefileBuild.vc`](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/curl-7_61_0/winbuild/MakefileBuild.vc). Zooming in to lines 87-93 of the latter, it has

```
87  BASE_NAME              = libcurl
88  BASE_NAME_DEBUG        = $(BASE_NAME)_debug
89  BASE_NAME_STATIC       = $(BASE_NAME)_a
90  BASE_NAME_STATIC_DEBUG = $(BASE_NAME_STATIC)_debug
91
92  LIB_NAME_STATIC        = $(BASE_NAME_STATIC).lib
93  LIB_NAME_STATIC_DEBUG  = $(BASE_NAME_STATIC_DEBUG).lib
```

With your selected options, this shows that the library name expands to `libcurl_a_debug.lib` for debug and `libcurl_a.lib` for non-debug. Further down the file, these names are used to define the target lib filename.

The only way to modify this seems to be changing the quoted lines to have them expand to your preferred names.

Comment: Thank you. I've missed those lines.